# Rails find_by_path method parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, find, where-clause, findby

I've been told that the `find_by_path` method may be a better solution than `where`

I have this snippet in a migration file ...

`prescriber_activity_request = InsightReportMenuItem.where(name: "Prescriber Activity With Patient").first`

I'm new to rails. My question is, if I can use `find_by_path` here, what does my path look like?

I guess I'm confused on how a database structures its paths.

Comment: `prescriber_activity_request = InsightReportMenuItem.find_by_name( "Prescriber Activity With Patient")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you need from the database. If you call .where, you will always get a non-nil result (if nothing is found that matches your condition it will be an empty array).

In your case, if nothing is found you'll get a nil error because calling .first on an empty array will error out.

If you're checking for the presence of a single record,

```
find_by_name('Prescriber Activity With Patient')
```

...is your find_by path. So you can do things like this

```
if @irmi = InsightReportMenuItem.find_by_name( "Prescriber Activity With Patient")
  #redirect to insight_report_menu_item_path(@irmi) or whatever
else
  #redirect_to root_path or whatever
end
```

If you're using .where you can use .any? and then call .first if .any? returns true. Hope that helps. And for the record, you can do find_by_(any attribute in your InsightReportMenuItem table). For example:

```
InsightReportMenuItem.find_by_id(1)
```

will produce the first one in the table.